Spring Boot & Jakarta Validation: Use group sequence by default
I am using Spring Boot 3 with Hibernate's Jakarta Validation. In my application, I have two groups of validations:

Default validations
Complex custom customizations that should only run if the default validations pass

I created a group sequence:
import jakarta.validation.GroupSequence;
import jakarta.validation.groups.Default;

@GroupSequence({Default.class, AllValidations.AfterDefaultValidations.class})
public interface AllValidations {

    interface AfterDefaultValidations {

    }
}

This sequence works as expected when I explicitly call it like this:
import jakarta.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
class MyService {
    
    private final Validator validator;

    public void myMethod(MyData data) {
        validator.validate(data, AllValidations.class);
        // ...
    }
}

However, I would like to avoid having to specify AllValidations.class every time I call validate or use the @Validated annotation. Is there a way to set this group sequence as the default, so that calling validate(data) automatically uses it?

You can use the @GroupSequence annotation to extend the default validation scope for a given class.
For example, if you add Foo.class group
@GroupSequence({Foo.class, A.class})
class A {

  @NotNull(groups = Foo.class)
  private Long foo;
}

Then validator.validate(new A()) will check if foo is not null too.
For more information, see the Hibernate Validator Reference Guide.

That's definitely an improvement, thanks! Though it still would require annotating all of my DTO classes for the application's APIs.
